# How can I remove the previous route from Router?

Tags: react-native

I'm using the [t4t5/react-native-router](https://github.com/t4t5/react-native-router) and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to remove the last route so that the user can't go back (after login).

Is there a way to reset the stack so the next route would be the root?

Note, I've also tried the React NavigatorIOS but it doesn't change the title on the new route (text is the same as initial route).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a issue about changing title when using `resetTo` : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/476.

Here's another possible solution: use Navigator (not NavigatorIOS). Basically, in `index.ios.js` we should do:

```
renderScene: function(route, nav) {
      switch (route.id) {
        case 'home':
          return <Home navigator={nav}/>;
        case 'login':
          return <Login navigator={nav}/>;
        case 'register':
          return <Register navigator={nav}/>
        default:
          return (
            <Login navigator={nav}/>
          );
      }

  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
      style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
      initialRoute={{ id: "login" }}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
      configureScene={(route) => {
          if (route.sceneConfig) {
              return route.sceneConfig;
          }
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight
        }
      }
    />
    )
  }
```

And if login is a success, in Login do this:

```
this.props.navigator.replace({ id: 'home' });
```

to replace current route so that user won't go back to Login.

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/leanote/leanote-ios).

Comment: Wow many thanks! This works great.

I gave up on Navigator on the first day as the verbose example in the docs confused me (also first day in React lol). 

I think the issue on NavigatorIOS was a bug with `resetTo`, as the title worked ok with `push`.

Comment: FWIW for future readers, the t4t5/react-native-router package didn't expose the navigaor via props and only had a toRoute method. I'll see if I can make a PR to fix this (or use the header UI code)

Comment: You're right, this is the related issue on github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/894